# Nice approach for redirecting request to correct application instance?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, design-patterns, spring-security

This is not a question but an effort to get the comments from experts out there.

Let’s consider, that there are 2 web applications, namely, “SPRING-WEB-APP-1” & “SPRING-WEB-APP-2”.

Now, both of these applications are supposed to be accessible by their own sets of users (i.e. “SPRING-WEB-APP-2” shouldn’t be accessible by “SPRING-WEB-APP-1-USERS” and vice versa).

Both applications are deployed on different instances of application servers as 2 separate WARS.

All HTTP requests shall land in “SPRING-WEB-APP-1” and requests shall be redirected/forwarded(based on the “Type Of Users”) to either of the one application mentioned above.

What will be an extensible and modular solution for this?

Well, I am thinking to create a Spring controller (named as “RequestRedirectionController”) for all incoming HTTP requests.

Said controller shall be responsible to test the type of user from which request came and will redirect request to either “SPRING-WEB-APP-1” or  “SPRING-WEB-APP-2”, through JSP forward.

Any comments shall be highly appreciated?

Comment: If one application must not be accessed by users of the other, and vice-verso, why have all users login to one of the applications?

Comment: Well, there is a transitioning(including users) happening from SPRING_WEB_APP-2 to SPRING_WEB_APP-1. so the users if moved from earlier one to the later one shall be redirected to SPRING_WEB_APP-1 or else to SPRING_WEB_APP-2.

Comment: So why not transition everything in one shot from one web application to the other? No need to do redirects then...

Comment: sorry for late response. let's come to your point. Well, what you said makes sense in an "ideal scenario". but things like "business continuity,budget etc." doesn't allow to do this. Take an example of Yahoo, it changed it's model & view but one fine day it didn't change it's billions of user's experience. If they tried to do so, their business would go on toss and that is the only reason why I posted for the above mentioned question but not getting expected views.